# How to put tab view in middle of layout

Tags: android, tabs

I am developing an app, requires following view  image [1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrNpS.png

My activity extends AppcompactActivity and using supporting action bar. so it can't extend TabActivity and also I dont want to use deprecated Tabactivity.

how can I put tabs in middle of layout, I think it may possible with 
fragments, is there any other way to achieve it. help me. Thanks.

Comment: use `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`

Comment: look a this https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip and even u can set tab anywhere in ur layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` and place it in the middle of your layout.

Some useful attributes:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
```